# Как можно передать динамический двумерный массив вертексов в функцию OpenGL?

Tags: c++, массивы, opengl, графика, динамические-массивы

Пишу на C++ с использованием библиотеки OpenGL. Код инициализации динамического массива vs:

```cpp
float some[4][3] = { { -.5, -.5, 0 }, { -.5, +.5, 0 }, { +.5, +.5, 0 }, { +.5, -.5, 0 } };
// Инициализация
float** vs;
vs = new float*[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { vs[i] = new float[3]; }
// Заполнение сомом
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    vs[i][j] = some[i][j];
  }
}
```

Фрагмент отрисовки:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vs);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Если делать так, то выводит непонятно что:
[![Если используется vs][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSUdp.png
[![Если используется some][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is5dK.png
В случае с vs - линия вниз и линия вбок, которая иногда мерцает и пропадает
В случае с some - всё прекрасно работает

Comment: Очевидно проблема в том, что `vs` - указывает на массив указателей, а не на массив `float`.

Comment: Уложи данные в 1-мерный массив, и передавай одномерный массив. В новом опенжл можно и покруче данные затолкать. glVertexPointer это легаси опенжл(так прямо на сайте опенжл написано) и юзать его не стоит. И вообще в C++ есть vector и не стоит делать float** vs; А вообще лучше не лезть в опенжл, ибо от него толку мало а проблем много. Есть же куча готовых рендер либ.